# AWS RDS db.t3.micro(POSTGRESQL) max user connections

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I'm new to AWS RDS and I just want to know how many concurrent user/client can connect to a database in my **db.t3.micro** POSTGRESQL and how many concurrent request can it handle ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For PostgreSQL 13, default `max_connections` value is calculated as:

```
LEAST({DBInstanceClassMemory/9531392},5000)
```

The `t3.micro` has `1GB` RAM, so it will be:

```
1*1024*1024*1024/9531392 = 112
```

So about **112 connections**.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you explain me the formula ?

Comment: @SURYA No problem. There is not much to explain. You check the RAM size of your db instance in GB, change to Bytes, and divide by 9531392.

Comment: Source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_Limits.html